# Neo4j index not working without the Using keyword

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

If I execute this query

```
match (p:Person),(c:Customer) using index p:Person(BusinessEntityID)  where p.BusinessEntityID = c.CustomerID return p
```

the response is very quick. 
If I remove the using keyword and execute this.

```
match (p:Person),(c:Customer)  where p.BusinessEntityID = c.CustomerID return p
```

, the query takes forever to return result. I have about 50,000 nodes. 
Also, the .Net client does not implement Using Index and I am basically stuck. 
Could you please help as to how I can speed up the query.

note: I have indexes created on both BusinessEntityID and CustomerID on labels :Person and :Customer respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. perhaps you should create a relationship between the two, not doing a manual join on a property?

Then, please change it to this:

```
match (c:Customer)
match (p:Person)
where p.BusinessEntityID = c.CustomerID 
return p
```